# Codeigniter not receiving request

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on implementing a payment/subscription solution (more specifically, MoIP payments from Brazil) into a Codeigniter project. Every time a subscription is created or altered in any way, as in when it's paid, it sends a notification to a pre configured URL.

My problem is: I can't seem to be able to receive the notifications on my project's designated URL / controller. The current payment method works in a similar fashion and the notifications are received with no problems.

I've tested with test-cors.org and the result is 200 OK for POST and GET methods. Accessing the method manually produces the log output. I've tried setting `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in the htaccess file and `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in the construct with no luck. Altering the htaccess actually results in an XHR code 0 return on test-cors.org.

I've created a Request Bin to show you guys how the request is structured: http://requestb.in/1l3wms21?inspect (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bf3B.png).

What could be the problem? I've run out of ideas. Here's the code in the receiver:

```
function process_notification() {
    log_message('info', 'http request: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $findme = "{";
    $pos = strpos($data, $findme);

     if ($pos === 0) {
        $ponteiro = fopen(FCPATH . "data.txt", "w");
        fwrite($ponteiro, $data);
        fclose($ponteiro);
    }

    if (filesize('data.txt')) {
        $ponteiro = fopen("data.txt", "r");
        $dataTXT = fread($ponteiro, filesize("data.txt"));
        echo("JSON: [");
        print_r($dataTXT);
        echo("]<br>");
        echo(FCPATH . "data.txt");
        fclose($ponteiro);
    }
    echo(print_r($_POST));

    log_message('info', '');
    log_message('info', 'notification received');
    log_message('info', print_r($_POST, true));
    log_message('info', '');
}
```

EDIT: adding the logs

Here's the browser output when accessed with the browser. The console is empty.

```
Array ( ) 1
```

Here are the codeigniter logs when accessed via the browser:

```
INFO  - 2014-08-22 16:19:03 --> http request: GET
INFO  - 2014-08-22 16:19:03 --> 
INFO  - 2014-08-22 16:19:03 --> notification received
INFO  - 2014-08-22 16:19:03 --> Array
(
)

INFO  - 2014-08-22 16:19:03 -->
```

Triggering the notification via subscribing does not output any log whatsoever. The `data.txt` file is empty regardless of browser or remote access.

Comment: Whats the log? And what about the console of the browser?

Comment: Added the logs, but they are virtually non-existent.

Comment: How the subscribing works when call this code? Add the log message method too please...

Comment: The notification is sent to this code. The subscription itself is handled in another block of code and generates these notifications http://requestb.in/1l3wms21?inspect

Comment: Oh and the `log_message` function is a core function from Codeigniter https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html